# Binding a datasource with some Enum values

Tags: c#, enums

How can I bind a DataSource with some selected enum values?

**My Enum:**

```
public enum Filters : byte
{
    Filter1 = 1,
    Filter2 = 2,
    Filter3 = 4,
    Filter4 = 8,
    Filter5 = 16
}
```

**Selected values:**

```
public Filters SelectedFilters = Filters.Filter1 | Filters.Filter4;
```

How can I bind the **SelectedFilters** variable as a datasource?

Comment: You might want to label the enum with the FlagsAttribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
public enum Filters : byte
{
    Filter1 = 1,
    Filter2 = 2,
    Filter3 = 4,
    Filter4 = 8,
    Filter5 = 16
}
```

And selecting some values:

```
public Filters SelectedFilters = Filters.Filter1 | Filters.Filter4;
```

I created a method that can solve my own question:

```
public static List<T> EnumToList<T>(Enum someEnum)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    foreach (var it in Enum.GetValues(someEnum.GetType()))
    {
        if ((Convert.ToByte(it) & Convert.ToByte(someEnum)) != 0)
        {
            list.Add((T)it);
        }
    }

    return list;
}


myRepeater.DataSource = EnumToList<Filters>(SelectedFilters);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to have the Text and Value of the DropDownList seperate, use a Dictionary like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> EnumToList(Type t)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> list = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(t))
    {
        list.Add((int)v, Enum.GetName(t, (int)v));
    }

    return list;
}
```

To use it, in the case of a LinqDataSource Selecting event:

```
protected void ldsMyTypes_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
     e.Result = EnumToList(typeof(Enums.FeedTypes));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Enum.GetNames(typeof(Filters ));
```