# How can I use an enum as a datasource?

Tags: c#, combobox, enums, datasource

I would like to use the values in an enum as the source for some comboboxes. This compiles, but doesn't populate the combobox:

```
private enum ValueType { Text, Barcode }

private ValueType vt;

private void FormCPCLCodeGenUtil_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBoxType1.DataSource = vt;
}
```

...which shouldn't surprise me, as vt hasn't been assigned a value; and I don't want the combobox to just have one value. So how can I do this (or is there a better way than using an enum as the data source)?

### UPDATE

A side question: which one of these is better, when several comboboxes will use the same data source :

```
    comboBoxType1.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ValueType)); 
    comboBoxFontSize1.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof (FontSizeType));
    comboBoxAlign1.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(AlignOptions));

    //comboBoxType2.DataSource = comboBoxType1.DataSource; 
    comboBoxType2.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ValueType));
```

(using the previously assigned comboboxes data source as its own, or connecting in the same way as the previous one?)

Comment: Clay there are so many examples of this on the web how come you refuse to use [Google](http://www.google.com) also here is a similar posting i found using `Google` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177915/binding-a-datasource-with-some-enum-values

Comment: I switched to Bing; the first two links didn't help, so I came here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this

```
comboBoxType1.DataSource= Enum.GetNames(typeof(ValueType));
```

Comment: Maybe also .ToList()